# Existence of a partial fraction decomposition of a rational function

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, partial-fractions, rational-functions

Consider the rational function $f(x)=\frac{x^2-3x-4}{x^2+1}$ my analysis prof gave us this definition of the partial fraction decomposition:

[image]

Given this definition I would argue that $f$ has no partial fraction decomposition since

$\deg(x^2-3x-4) = \deg(x^2+1)$

Is this correct or can you still find a representation and if so how?

EDIT:

By performing euclidian division I obtain:

$f(x)= 1 - \frac{3x+5}{x^2+1}$

Now I would have to find a decomposition of $\frac{-3x+5}{x^2+1}$ this clearly would be complex since $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$ but the given exercise problem says that I should only consider decompositions in the real numbers. Does that mean there is none?

Comment: You only have to perform the euclidean division in order to have a numerator of degree less than $2$.

Comment: Alright, then I obtain $f(x) = 1 - \frac{3x+5}{x^2+1}$ right? Then I would have to find the partial fraction decomp. of $\frac{3x+5}{x^2+1}$ and then I struggle since our exercise problem says that we should only consider the decomp. in the reals so no complex numbers but $x^2+1 = (x+i)(x-i)$

Comment: You just have to split the last fraction in two, to obtain  $\ln(x^2+1)$, up to a constant factor, and a term in $\arctan x$.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more in detail, where are ln and arctan coming from?

Comment: It is a basic formula that $\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan x$. As to the other one, $\int\frac{x\,\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}=\frac12\ln(1+x^2)$, using the substitution $u=1+x^2$, $\mathrm du=2x\,\mathrm dx$. Is it clearer?